# C++ write text to file, how to multiple lines

Tags: c++, writetofile

How do you write multiple lines to a file? ... This is what I have.. Also, some of the lines include text like: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` How would I go about doing this? The code below is what I have right now..

```
//Creates Config.h
        FILE * pFile;
        char *buffer = "//Empty Header File";
        char file [256];
        sprintf (file , "%s/Desktop/%s/Control.h",homeDir, game_name);
        pFile = fopen (file, "w+");
        fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
        fclose (pFile);
```

Comment: Do you want to use C or C++?

Comment: If you want to use the `C` functions like now, the endline character is `\n`. If you want to switch to `c++`, use `std::endl`.

Comment: Are you trying to append the content of `buffer` to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, I suggest you utilize the standard IOStreams library and use the concrete file stream classes `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` for handling files. They implement [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to handle the closing of the file, and use built in operators and the `read()`/`write()` member functions to perform formatted and unformatted I/O respectively. Moreover, they blend well together with the use of `std::basic_string`, the standard C++ string class.

With that said, if we implement this in C++ correctly, it should look like this:

```
std::string path     = "/Desktop/";
std::string filename = homeDir + path + game_name + "/Control.h";

std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios_base::app);
```

This handles opening the file, but as you say you wish to write multiple lines to a file. Well this is simple. Just use `'\n'` whenever you wish to put a newline:

```
file << buffer << '\n';
```

If you give us more information about your issue, I will be able to elaborate more in my answer. But until you do, the above is sufficient.

Comment: I like the explanation, but the filename isn't correct.  As it stands, the result will be equivalent to `std::string filename = homeDir + "%s/Desktop/%s/Control.h";` which isn't what is desired.  It should be more like `std::string filename = homeDir + "/Desktop/" + game_name + "/Control.h";`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
sprintf (file , "%s/Desktop/%s/Control.h\n",homeDir, game_name);
```

\n - is a new-line code.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you would do it like this:

```
ofstream fout("someplace/Control.h");
fout << "a line of text" << endl;
fout << "another line of text" << endl;
```

I've left out some details like how to construct a filename and how to open a file in "append" mode, but you should try to tackle one problem at a time.